# problems updating to new version of prawn on production server with bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, prawn, prawnto

I have updated my code etc to work with the 0.10.2 version and its all
working in development.

When i deployed to my production server and done a bundle install i
still get this errors?

git://github.com/sandal/prawn (at 0.10.2) is not checked out. Please
run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)

I then run bundle install again and get this error

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bundler/gems/prawn-89ba0ebf7ac3/
prawn.gemspec:2: warning: already initialized constant PRAWN_VERSION

Can anyone help with this PLEASE ?

thanks alot
rick

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and resolved it by removing the prawn submodules in git.